# "Infinite City" - hyperbolic geometry, or something else?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Background: I'm doing worldbuilding for my D&D world, and I want one location to be an "infinite city": finite circumference from the outside, but as you move toward the "center" there's always more room and space to go.

A specific detail I'd like is for "ring roads" circumnavigating the space inside to exist, and have larger circumference as you go further "in".

I *think* this can be described by saying that the region of space has a highly-curved hyperbolic geometry. Is this correct? If not, is there another way of describing the space that would have the effect I want? It's okay if the resulting geometry wouldn't be suitable for physics as we know it, I'm fine with hand-waving "it's magic!" to handle that; I'd just like something I can think about and possibly obtain some non-obvious interesting details from, and get a consistent description out of.

Comment: Let's take the rubber-sheet metaphor of general relativity: the surface of the world appears flat to its residents, but it's actually curved in a way that distances and circumferences don't act as they would in Euclidean geometry. Imagine the city is like a cone rising up from the plane of the world; then it's farther to the center than you would expect from measuring the circumference from the outside. Make the cone steeper and steeper until it's a cylinder; then you can keep going infinitely far towards the "center", and all ring roads have the same circumference. Now make it wider still...

Comment: 1. Do you want the distance to the center be finite? 2. Accordingly, do you want ring roads to me metric circles centered at the center (i.e. each road to be constant distance from the center)?

Comment: @Rahul Ooh, interesting. I was thinking of a Gabriel's Trumpet situation, but that would give shrinking rings; I don't know why I didn't think of letting the "tube" just get wider instead.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Distance to the center should be infinite. Ring roads should be centered on the infinitely-distance center; distance-wise they should be a constant distance from the (circular) boundary.

Comment: I think you want https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @rschwieb I thought about that, but this is really a math question that is just incidentally a world-building detail. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such examples are easy to construct indeed using classical hyperbolic geometry; however, you need to know some differential geometry.

Start with the upper half-plane ${\mathbb H}^2$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$ equipped with the hyperbolic metric 
$$
ds^2= y^{-2}( dx^2 + dy^2). $$

Next, consider the rectangular (in the Euclidean sense) region 
$$
Q=\{(x,y): 0\le x\le 2\pi, 0< y\le 1\} \subset {\mathbb H}^2.$$

Identify the vertical boundary intervals of $Q$ via horizontal translations:
$$
(0,y)\sim (2\pi,y), 0< y\le 1.
$$
The quotient space $A$ is diffeomorphic to the half-open annulus (a closed disk with the center removed),
$$
A\cong S^1\times (0,1]\cong D =\{w\in {\mathbb C}: 0< |w|\le \frac{1}{e}\}
$$
 The hyperbolic metric $ds^2$ projects to a Riemannian metric on $A$ (since horizontal translations are isometries of the hyperbolic metric). You can  realize this diffeomorphism  via the map 
$$
z=x+iy\mapsto w=\exp( i x - y^{-1}), z\in Q, w\in D. 
$$
Your concentric roads $C_r$ in $D$ are the Euclidean circles $|w|=r$. But the hyperbolic lengths $L_r$ of such roads are equal to 
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{y}= \frac{2\pi}{y},
$$
where 
$$
r= \exp(-y^{-1}), y= \frac{-1}{\ln(r)}.
$$
 Hence, as $r\to 0$,  $L_r\to\infty$.  The distance between $C_r$ and the exterior road $C_{1/e}$ is constant, equal 
$-\ln(y)$, where $y= \frac{-1}{\ln(r)}$. The distance from any point of $D$ to the center is infinite: If $w\in D$ corresponds to $z=x+iy$ then the distance from $w$ to $0$ equals
$$
\int_{0}^y \frac{dt}{t}= - \lim_{t\to 0} \ln(t)= + \infty. 
$$
The total area of $D$ is infinite as well (you compute it using the same integral).

Answer (score -1):

The (Poincaré model of the) hyperbolic plane is *slightly* different from what you want: it looks like a circle, but as you move outwards from the centre you become ''smaller'' from the god's perspective, and will never reach the edge.

Your description may be impossible to realise as a Riemannian manifold, but I can't prove that yet.

Comment: That's not what the question asked.